# Is there a way to write single instruction for fractional multiplication?

Tags: assembly, multiplication, fractions, 68000, easy68k

I am trying to write a single 68000 instruction to multiply the 32-bit  unsigned value in D0 by 0.125. Yet fractional multiplication is not available. So I am wondering if there is any way to go around it? It's supposed to be unsigned and 0.125 = 1/8. Thus, the way I thought it would work is:

```
LSL (LSR #0,#3),D0
```

This didn't even run, and I have no idea how else I could do it.

Comment: Please read this as a precursor to assembly language: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-address_code

Answer (score 1):

This is assembly, you cannot just compose expressions combining instructions like that. Each instruction needs to be on its own line. If you want to implement `(x >> 3) << 3` you'll have to first shift right, then shift left, which are two separate instructions:

```
LSR.L #3,D0
LSL.L #3,D0
```

By the way, note that `(x >> N) << N` is equivalent to `x & -(1 << N)`, which in the case of `N=3` is: `x & -8`, or in 68k assembly `AND.L #-8,D0` (or in hex `AND.L #$fffffff7,D0`).

However, if you want to just multiply by 0.125 (i.e. divide by 8), one right shift will suffice:

```
LSR.L #3,D0
```

Comment: If you want to round down to a multiple of 8, one `and` instruction can do it more efficiently than right + left shift.

Comment: @PeterCordes yep.. not sure what OP was after with that "instruction" really.

Comment: Neither am I, but that's what your `lsr` + `lsl` combo does, so you should optimize it instead of suggesting that's a sequence of instructions you'd ever want to use in a program.  I assume m68k has sign-extended immediates for AND instructions, or at worst that an `and` is no larger than 2 shifts.

Comment: @PeterCordes well, sure, but I wasn't trying to explain the optimal way of rounding, I was just explaining how to properly combine the instruction. What OP really wants is just a single shift. Whatever I'll just add it for the sake of it.

Comment: `and #-8, d0` *does* implement `(x >> 3) << 3`.  That's what compilers do (for other ISAs) https://godbolt.org/z/rf5qa8, so it's a bit of an overstatement to say you *have* to do it with shifts.  That's only if you want to implement it *as written*.  I see you already updated, but you got it backwards: `x & 7` is `x<<(16-3) >> (16-3)` to keep only the low 3 bits, instead of clearing those.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to acheive with:

```
LSL (LSR #0,#3),D0
```

If you want to logical-shift-right the value in `d0` by three bits (i.e., divide by `8`, or multiply by `0.125`), that would be the much simpler:

```
lsr #$03, d0 ;; or lsr.l
```